# Fetch JSON from same Server (localhost) but different Virtual Host

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, craftcms, react-static

I'm having quite a basic issue I suppose. I've set up CraftCMS to be reachable via Apache Virtual Host `http://craftapi` and am using Element API with routes such as `http://craftapi/projects?page=1` etc.

On a separate Virtual Host `http://mysite` I've set up a react-static install which should fetch the JSON using Axios from `http://craftapi/projects?page=1` but it throws after `Importing routes from directory...` with:

> Error: socket hang up

Am I not allowed to fetch from a different domain? Even if it is hosted on the same server?

Thanks

Comment: You can either enable CORS for your apis (http://craftapi/...), or create a proxy for your apis on the (http://mysite) so that all the request `http://mysite/api/*` is forwared to `http://craftapi/*`

Comment: Thanks @SujeetJaiswal. Also I found this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/